# extract columns by indices in a conditionally subsetted dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 4))
df.columns = ['a','b','c','d']
print(df)
          a         b         c         d
0  2.454522  1.609990  1.218581 -0.133827
1  0.462152  0.939479 -0.626329  1.169886
2  0.334338 -1.188042 -1.387660 -1.874766
3  0.576941 -0.362167  2.321634  1.415192
4 -0.234557 -1.468935 -1.090757  1.392798
5 -1.316241  0.939276  0.508557  1.187436
6  1.140832  1.588225 -0.046766 -0.329412
7 -1.533695 -0.565144 -0.133613 -1.941484
```

I want to select the rows of second column where values are greater than zero. This I am able to do  by

```
df1 = df.loc[df.iloc[:,0] >= 0]
          a         b         c         d
0  2.454522  1.609990  1.218581 -0.133827
1  0.462152  0.939479 -0.626329  1.169886
2  0.334338 -1.188042 -1.387660 -1.874766
3  0.576941 -0.362167  2.321634  1.415192
6  1.140832  1.588225 -0.046766 -0.329412
```

But my requirement is that df1 should contain just second and fourth columns.

```
          b         d
0  1.609990 -0.133827
1  0.939479  1.169886
2 -1.188042 -1.874766
3 -0.362167  1.415192
6  1.588225 -0.329412
```

This I can do by

```
df1 = df1.iloc[:, [1,3]]
```

Bow can I do that in same line of code where I am applying condition on rows, using both column names and indices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select columns with indexing:

```
print (df.columns[[1,3]])
Index(['b', 'd'], dtype='object')

df1 = df.loc[df.iloc[:,0] >= 0, df.columns[[1,3]]]
print (df1)
          b         d
0  1.609990 -0.133827
1  0.939479  1.169886
2 -1.188042 -1.874766
3 -0.362167  1.415192
6  1.588225 -0.329412
```

because solution with `iloc` is not implemented:

```
df1 = df.iloc[df.iloc[:,0] >= 0, [1,3]]
```

> NotImplementedError: iLocation based boolean indexing on an integer type is not available

but if convert mask to numpy array it working nice:

```
df1 = df.iloc[df.iloc[:,0].values >= 0, [1,3]]
print (df1)
          b         d
0  1.609990 -0.133827
1  0.939479  1.169886
2 -1.188042 -1.874766
3 -0.362167  1.415192
6  1.588225 -0.329412
```

---

And with columns names it is simplier:

```
df1 = df.loc[df.iloc[:,0] >= 0, ['b','d']]
print (df1)
          b         d
0  1.609990 -0.133827
1  0.939479  1.169886
2 -1.188042 -1.874766
3 -0.362167  1.415192
6  1.588225 -0.329412
```

EDIT:

There is small typo, for second column need `df.iloc[:,1]`:

```
df1 = df.loc[df.iloc[:,1] >= 0, df.columns[[1,3]]]
df1 = df.iloc[df.iloc[:,1].values >= 0, [1,3]]
df1 = df.loc[df.iloc[:,1] >= 0, ['b','d']]
```

---

```
print (df1)

          b         d
0  1.609990 -0.133827
1  0.939479  1.169886
5  0.939276  1.187436
6  1.588225 -0.329412
```

Comment: How to do it using column names?